# How to hide menu when you click outside it in react?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I build a CRUD Web App with React and Tailwind. I created a navbar with dropdown menu when app is displayed on mobile.

I display menu when you click on the button but I don't know how to hide menu when you click outside the menu with React.

[image]

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const NavBar = () => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const displayResponsiveMenu = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
    }

    return (
        <nav>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">

                ...

                <div className="block lg:hidden">
                    <button onClick={displayResponsiveMenu} className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
                        {
                            !isOpen ?
                                <svg className="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" /></svg>
                                :
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" className="w-3 h-3">
                                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                                </svg>
                        }
                    </button>
                </div>

                ...

            </div>
            {
                isOpen ?
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 pl-6 pt-2 pb-2">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/users" className="block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4">
                                    Users
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> : null
            }
        </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar
```

Comment: Thanks @adampweb but the answer isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

**Edit:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const menuRef = useRef(null);
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const displayResponsiveMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
    if (
      menuRef.current &&
      !menuRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
      event.target !== buttonRef.current
    ) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
        <div className="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            strokeWidth="1.5"
            stroke="currentColor"
            className="w-6 h-6"
          >
            <path
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              d="M15.75 6a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0zM4.501 20.118a7.5 7.5 0 0114.998 0A17.933 17.933 0 0112 21.75c-2.676 0-5.216-.584-7.499-1.632z"
            />
          </svg>
          <span className="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight ml-2">
            Random User App
          </span>
        </div>
        <div className="block lg:hidden">
          <button
            ref={buttonRef}
            onClick={displayResponsiveMenu}
            className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white"
          >
            {isOpen ? (
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                strokeWidth="1.5"
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-3 h-3"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                />
              </svg>
            ) : (
              <svg
                className="fill-current h-3 w-3"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <title>Menu</title>
                <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
              </svg>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          className="w-full lg:block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto hidden"
          ref={menuRef}
        >
          <div className="text-lg lg:flex-grow">
            <Link
              to="/users"
              className="block mt-4 lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
            >
              Users
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 pl-6 pt-2 pb-2">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link
                to="/users"
                className="block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4"
              >
                Users
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

### Explanation:

1. **Create a new reference called buttonRef to refer to the menu button element.**

   `const buttonRef = useRef(null);`

This reference will be used to store a reference to the menu button element. We will attach this reference to the menu button element in the JSX code using the `ref` attribute.

2. **In the `handleOutsideClick` function, add an additional condition to check if the clicked target (`event.target`) matches the reference to the menu button (`buttonRef.current`). If the click target is the menu button, we should not close the menu.**

   ```
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
    if (
      menuRef.current &&
      !menuRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
      event.target !== buttonRef.current
    ) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
   };
   ```

In this step, we modify the `handleOutsideClick` function to include an extra check: `event.target !== buttonRef.current`. This condition checks if the clicked target is not the same as the menu button (`buttonRef.current`). If the click target is the menu button, we know that the user clicked on the menu button itself, and in such case, we don't want to close the menu. This prevents the menu from closing immediately after opening it.

**4: The `useEffect` hook is used to add an event listener for `mousedown` events on the document, and the `handleOutsideClick` function is called when a `mousedown` event occurs.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick);
  };
}, []);
```

In this step, we use the `useEffect` hook to add an event listener for `mousedown` events on the entire document. We do this by calling `document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleOutsideClick)`. This allows us to detect clicks anywhere on the page. We use the cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook to remove the event listener when the component is unmounted. This ensures that we clean up any previously added event listeners to avoid potential memory leaks.

Hope it helps. Feel free to accept this as the answer if it works.

Comment: @ Swapnil Prakash Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why you add ```document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick);``` in the return of the function useEffect, please ?

Comment: @Popovkov57 Adding `document.removeEventListener('click', handleOutsideClick)` in the useEffect hook is important to ensure that event listeners are properly removed when the component is unmounted or updated.

Comment: @ Swapnil Prakash Could you add explanation and details each steps in your answer please ? Thanks

Comment: @ Swapnil Prakash . I test your answer and It doesn't work.

Comment: @Popovkov57 I have edited the answer. Check if this one works. I am really sorry for any inconvenience caused earlier.

Comment: @ Swapnil Prakash It's work. It's my fault. I should have tested before  Thank you.